# Block on wedge problem without any kind of friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

The question is as follows:

[image]

I did the following:

force on m<sub>1</sub> = m<sub>1</sub>g sin(45)
thus acceleration of m<sub>1</sub> with respect to m<sub>2</sub> = g sin(45)

coming to m<sub>2</sub>,
force on m<sub>2</sub> due to m<sub>1</sub> = m<sub>1</sub>g cos(45)

but this is in diagonal direction, so we need to resolve it.

thus horizontal component = m<sub>1</sub>gcos(45) * sin(45)

now acceleration of m<sub>2</sub> with respect to ground will be force/mass
thus acceleration = m<sub>1</sub>g cos(45)sin(45) / m<sub>2</sub> = g/4 ( on substituting values )

for m<sub>1</sub> :

h$√2$ = 1/2*a*t<sup>2</sup>

again putting values, we have t<sup>2</sup> = 2h/5

for m<sub>2</sub> :
distance = 1/2 * g/4 * 2h/5 = h/2

but correct answer is h/4.

they used concept of center of mass

I prefer my method.

someone please help me understand where I went wrong

Comment: I get $\frac{h}{3}$ after considering pseudo force. Is the final answer $\frac{h}{4}$ correct?

Comment: @om jogekar I think h/3 is correct. I think you forgot to consider pseudo force.

Comment: We all prefer our original method because we are more comfortable in it. But centre of mass method makes it much much easier to solve this. It will help you for JEE :p

Comment: @Iti yes h/4 is correct. see the solution below

Comment: @DheerajKumar h/3 is wrong. see below

Comment: Since $m_2$ is accelerating and carries with it a non-inertial frame of reference, the acceleration of  $m_1$ relative to $m_2$ is not 'g sin(45)'.

Comment: Hint for the easy approach: momentum is conserved, and the center of mass doesn't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the Free Body Diagram of block,
$N_1+m_1a\cos45°=m_1g\cos45°\tag{1}$
(As block moves only on the surface with respect to wedge)
$m_1a\cos45°+m_1g\sin45°=m_1a_1\tag{2}$
From the Free body diagram of wedge,
$N_1\cos45°=m_2a=2m_1a\tag{3}$
From (3),
$N_1=2\sqrt{2}m_1a$

Putting $N_1$ in (1) gives
$a=\frac{g}{5}$

Putting $a$ in (2) gives,
$a_1=\frac{6g}{5\sqrt{2}}$

The block is initially at rest and the hypotenuse of wedge is      $\frac{h}{\sin45°}$
So, by $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}a_1t^2$
$\frac{h}{\sin45°}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{6g}{5\sqrt{2}}t^2$
$\implies t^2=\frac{10h}{3g}$

At, the same time $t$ wedge moves by some distance say $s$ leftwards, given by
$s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$
$\implies s=\frac{1}{2}\frac{g}{5}\frac{10h}{3g}$
Hence, $s=\frac{h}{3}$
So distance moved by wedge =$\frac{h}{3}$

Comment: In the fbd of block, I used the fact that wedge is sttaionary by inserting pseudo force in the equation of block and then it will move only on the surface repative to wedge.

Comment: i am so sorry for misleading you
your answers were right
it is h/3
the textbook was wrong
my teacher clarified it.